# du command gives error and result at the same time

Tags: disk-usage

I would like to know the disk space of my VPS, and although for folders `du` works fine as

```
$ du -sh /home/
325M    /var/
```

But trying to get the entire vps is giving me this result.

```
[root@user/]# du -sh
du: cannot access `./proc/18097/task/18097/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/18097/task/18097/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/18097/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `./proc/18097/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
1.3G    .
```

I am assuming 1.3G is the space, but why does the error happen? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to fix that - it's not broken. Those are references to kernel file objects that are not available to `du` - it's a common race condition involving file descriptors. Those consume no space anyway *(and neither does `/proc`, for that matter)* as they are not on disk - they are only temporary references to in-kernel file-descriptors. They are either referencing *anonymous pipes/sockets* - and so are not `stat`able as they have no filename - or between the time that `du` notices them and the time it tries to `stat` them they have either ceased to exist or `du` never had permissions to do so in the first place. They are very likely `du`'s own file descriptors.

However, your command might have issues in that it addresses multiple file-system mounts. This is probably not your intent, and so you could use:

```
du -shx
```

...to address only files that exist on the current working directory's root mount. Because `/proc` is a file-system all its own and is mounted separately to `/` running that from `/` would exclude `/proc` and all others which do not belong.

Else, if you do want listings for multiple file-system mounts, you can just do:

```
du -sh 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I didn't get 'they are not on disk'. Where are those file descriptors then?

Comment: @crisron - they exist in system memory if at all

Comment: Because in Unix everything is a file - this is the main storage/access abstraction - even the stuff that is in memory needs to be referenced as files and directories.